# Prestashop: override core module class

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I would like to override the HomeSlide class for the module homeslider, for that I created a file HomeSlide.php and i placed it under `override/modules/homeslider`. I tried this `HomeSlide.php` :

```
class HomeSlide  extends HomeSlideCore
{
    public $start_date;
    public $end_date;

    public  function __construct($id_slide = null, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
    {
        self::$definition['fields']['start_date'] =   array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate');
        self::$definition['fields']['end_date'] =   array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate');

        parent::__construct($id_slide, $id_lang, $id_shop);
    }
}
```

But I got this error

```
 Class 'HomeSlideCore' not found
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah the problem is that `HomeSlide` class is not a Prestashop core class but a class used by a module which means you can't override it like this.

Simplest way is to just alter the `HomeSlide` class and alter it again after any module updates (It's not a good practice but alternatives aren't much better).

Another way to do this is by overriding the module itself and include your extended version of the `HomeSlide` class.

Extended `HomeSlide` class

```php
require_once 'path_to_original_homeslide_class';

class MyHomeSlide extends HomeSlide
{
    // Your overrides for the class
}
```

Overriden `HomeSlider` module

```
require_once 'path_to_my_homeslide_class';

class HomeSliderOverride extends HomeSlider
{
     // Module method overrides
}
```

Problem with this approach is that you will have to copy paste into overriden module every method from module which uses `HomeSlide` class and replace that with `MyHomeSlide`. It can be a nuisance if the original module gets these methods updated and you have to repeat the copy pasting process again. Which is pretty much the same as just altering the original class so not much gained here.

The third option is to override this module or create a new module and use a hook `actionDispatcher` to alter the `HomeClass`.

```
public function hookActionDispatcher()
{
    // Add class definitions on every page load - add some checks if module is loaded only on certain pages
    require_once 'path_to_homeslide_class';

    HomeSlide::$definition['fields']['start_date'] = array('type' => ObjectModel::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate');
    HomeSlide::$definition['fields']['end_date'] = array('type' => ObjectModel::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate');
}
```

However a big problem here is that there's no (simple) way to add non-static properties without an instance at runtime. It can be done with [monkey patching](https://github.com/juanmf/SourceEditor) but that's not considered a good practice.

**TL;DR**

Modify the original file or have your custom data in a separate table in a 1:1 relation with `homeslider_slides` table and use object model hooks to detect insert/update/delete events.

Comment: Hi,

I know this topic is old but I'm trying to achieve almost the same and I was wondering if 4 years later, there is maybe another better way to do it?

I managed to do the override of `ps_imageslider.php` but couldn't figure a way to override the ObjectModel `Ps_HomeSlide.php` ; the only working solution I found is the first one @TheDrot is listing: do the modification in the original `Ps_HomeSlide.php` file.

I'll be glad to give more information if it can help. :)
Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cant override modules in the same way as class, in class you had to do this using:

`class SomeClass extends SomeClassCore`

but in module you have use this way:

`class BlockUserInfoOverride extends BlockUserInfo`

so you need to use word Override not Core.

Check here http://build.prestashop.com/howtos/module/how-to-override-modules/

Comment: I'm overriding a class in a module (HomeSlider) not the one that contains the install (homeslide.php) your solution is not a solution for my request